# Can I add a hyperlink inside a message box of a Google Apps spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to add a hyperlink inside a message box of a Google Apps spreadsheet?

I have this code that displays a msgbox.

```
// The code below will display a message box
Browser.msgBox("Go to this site for help");
}
```

Is there a way to insert a hyperlink in that message box as well?   Something like:

```
// The code below will display a message box
Browser.msgBox("Go to this site for help" & <a href="www.google.com">Help</a>);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a popup showing a link to an url

```
function showurl() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('60').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("Anchor in a popup ;-)");
  var panel = app.createPopupPanel()
  var link = app.createAnchor('This is your link', 'https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home');
  panel.add(link);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to replace the link with a button that achieves the same result? (opening a new page)

Comment: You can create a button inside the pop up UI but not a button 'alone', see this post to see how to "disguise" a link with a button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875759/use-button-to-open-url-in-new-window-with-google-appsscript/22884575#22884575

Comment: This code is now deprecated, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40225227/1966294).

Answer (score 13):

Google's UI service is deprecated as of Dec. 11, 2014. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app).

You should now use the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/). The code to display a message with a link is below.

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('Go to <a href="https://www.google.ca/">this site</a> for help!')
    .setWidth(250) //optional
    .setHeight(50); //optional
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Help Dialog Title');
```

It appears Google Sheets won't run scripts for anyone who opens a public spreadsheet (obviously for security). If you want to see a live version of the dialog, just copy the above code into `function onOpen() {}` in the script editor, save & refresh the spreadsheet. Otherwise, it looks like the image below.

[image: Help Dialog Example]

If you have more HTML than a simple link, you can also create a dialog from an HTML file. In the script editor, select **File** > **New** > **Html file** and name it "index" (or whatever you want and change file name in code).

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
```

Comment: Works very nicely, you can add target=_blank if you want the URL to open in a new tab, rather than in the modal

Comment: Newbie having a problem, added your code (thanks!) to onOpen function in Google Sheets, but it doesn't run when I open the spreadsheet.  It DOES run from the script editor when I click "Run" there. I also tried using an alert instead in onOpen, and this runs when opening the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. Message boxes do not accept hyperlinks or  tags. Plain text only.

Comment: As a workaround, use the DisplayPopupPanel() in your UiInstance to display the link you want.  You can create a "dialog-like" look this way.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any links to an example of this?