# Google Apps Script to open a URL

Tags: html, redirect, google-apps-script, hyperlink

Is there a way to write a google apps script so when ran, a second browser window opens to www.google.com (or another site of my choice)?

I am trying to come up with a work-around to my previous question here:
[Can I add a hyperlink inside a message box of a Google Apps spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622521/can-i-add-a-hyperlink-inside-a-message-box-of-a-google-apps-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can build a small UI that does the job like this :

```
function test(){
showURL("http://www.google.com")
}
//
function showURL(href){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(50).setWidth(200);
  app.setTitle("Show URL");
  var link = app.createAnchor('open ', href).setId("link");
  app.add(link);  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
  }
```

If you want to 'show' the URL, just change this line like this :

```
  var link = app.createAnchor(href, href).setId("link");
```

EDIT : [link to a demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dEhNZlA0NTFOWVZIb25iNk5Wa1VaalE) in *read only* because too many people keep writing unwanted things on it (just make a copy to use instead).

**EDIT : UiApp was deprecated by Google on 11th Dec 2014, this method could break at any time and needs updating to use HTML service instead!**

EDIT : 
below is an implementation using html service.

```
function testNew(){
  showAnchor('Stackoverflow','http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

Comment: see edit, I added a example spreadsheet to show you hor it should be used.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  The example spreadsheet is in view only mode so it does not allow me to get to the script editor.  But, for some reason, now the above scrip works.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Info:  see also this other post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151564/how-do-i-open-a-web-browser-using-google-apps-script/18152436#18152436

Comment: For those of you checking this out in the year 2018 or later, the above solution no longer works. Please see Stephen M Harris' answer. Works as of the date of writing this comment.

Comment: sorry but that is not true, the new version as EDIT works , it uses HTMLService.

Comment: Just a note for anyone trying to use the updated method. If you are trying to open a webpage by running this code from pure Google App Script without it being part of a google sheet will get an error. Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. You will have to use the code inside a spreadsheet or use another method all together.

Answer (score 54):

This function opens a URL **without requiring additional user interaction**.

```
/**
 * Open a URL in a new tab.
 */
function openUrl( url ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

This method works by creating a temporary dialog box, so it will not work in contexts where the UI service is not accessible, such as the script editor or a custom G Sheets formula.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov indeed it does! I just updated the code with a fix.  It appears programmatic clicks have long been problematic in Firefox, but now the script reliably shows the 'Failed to open' fallback in Firefox and offers the user a working link.

Comment: Stephen, i do not follow the above script.  When i run it, it goes to an error page saying the URL was not found.  Can you post up an example of a code that will open a site like google.com?

Comment: @PY_ you can pass any URL you want to the function.  To open google.com, include the above script, then call `openUrl( 'https://google.com' );`

Comment: @StephenM.Harris - When you substitue SpreadsheetApp for DocumentApp, it opens two new windows (same url). Any suggestions about how to fix it? I'm trying to limit the scopes in my Google Doc addon.

Comment: @PY_, I had same issue, you need to include `http://` at beginning of urls, then it works

Comment: This is so great! Thanks!

Comment: This suddenly stopped working for me. I noticed Brave was blocking popups. In the URL bar, I then chose "always allow popups and redirects from docs.google.com." But still it wouldn't work. I notice a console error `"There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit"`. I don't know what changed recently that is causing this problem.

Comment: The following still didn't solve it for me, but I think I'm getting closer. I wonder why Google is suddenly requiring me to explicitly define all of these scopes in `appsscript.json` that I didn't before: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)  Requires authorization with this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

Comment: I again got Google Sheets App Script to open a URL in a new window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69015165/470749

Comment: Error: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit"

Answer (score 17):

There really isn't a need to create a custom click event as suggested in the bountied answer or  to show the url as suggested in the accepted answer.

`window.open(url)`[<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) does open web pages automatically without user interaction, provided pop- up blockers are disabled(as is the case with Stephen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098533))

#### openUrl.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <base target="_blank">
    <script>
     const url1 ='https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675103';
     const winRef = window.open(url1);
     winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Allow popup to redirect you to '+url1) ;
     window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('url').href = url1;}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Kindly allow pop ups</br>
    Or <a id='url'>Click here </a>to continue!!!
  </body>
</html>
```

#### code.gs:

```js
function modalUrl(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .showModalDialog(
     HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(50),
     'Opening StackOverflow'
   )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I liked @Stephen M. Harris's answer, and it worked for me until recently. I'm not sure why it [stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/47098533#comment121863283_47098533).

### What works for me now on 2021-09-01:

```
function openUrl( url ){
  Logger.log('openUrl. url: ' + url);
  const html = `<html>
<a id='url' href="${url}">Click here</a>
  <script>
     var winRef = window.open("${url}");
     winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Configure browser to allow popup to redirect you to ${url}') ;
     </script>
</html>`; 
  Logger.log('openUrl. html: ' + html);
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth( 250 ).setHeight( 300 );
  Logger.log('openUrl. htmlOutput: ' + htmlOutput);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( htmlOutput, `openUrl function in generic.gs is now opening a URL...` ); // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)  Requires authorization with this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)  Requires authorization with this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

Comment: Seems similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675103/8404453)

Comment: How could this be modified to include data from cell A2 into the URL, e.g. to run a google search for the data in A2

Comment: It is working for me.  This work around is excellent and very easy. The other solution does not work for me. Besides you have to create a new HTML file.  If you create an HTML file i encountered "function not found error"

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 4):

Google Apps Script will not open automatically web pages, but it could be used to display a message with links, buttons that the user could click on them to open the desired web pages or even to use the [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and methods like [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to open URLs.

It's worth to note that UiApp is now deprecated. From [Class UiApp - Google Apps Script - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app)

> Deprecated. The UI service was [deprecated on December 11, 2014](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html). To
>   create user interfaces, use the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) instead.

The example in the HTML Service linked page is pretty simple,

Code.gs

```
// Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

A customized version of index.html to show two hyperlinks

```
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>Stack Overflow</a>
<br/>
<a href='http://meta.stackoverflow.com/' target='_blank'>Meta Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: window.open(url, "_blank") can be used to open a web page.

Answer (score 3):

Building of off an earlier example, I think there is a cleaner way of doing this. Create an `index.html` file in your project and using Stephen's code from above, just convert it into an HTML doc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function onSuccess(url) {
      var a = document.createElement("a"); 
      a.href = url;
      a.target = "_blank";
      window.close = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          google.script.host.close();
        }, 9);
      };
      if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
          window.document.body.append(a);
        }                        
        event.initEvent("click", true, true); 
        a.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        a.click();
      }
      close();
    }

    function onFailure(url) {
      var div = document.getElementById('failureContent');
      var link = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Process</a>';
      div.innerHtml = "Failure to open automatically: " + link;
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).getUrl();
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="failureContent"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    google.script.host.setHeight(40);
    google.script.host.setWidth(410);
  </script>
</html>
```

Then, in your `Code.gs` script, you can have something like the following,

```
function getUrl() {
  return 'http://whatever.com';
}

function openUrl() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  html.setWidth(90).setHeight(1);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Comment: I tried this example. It was working perfectly fine a few days back. Today when I am running it, it only opens the dialog but does not open the external url in a new tab. Is there some setting that has gone wrong in my browser?

Comment: @shanti Did you ever figure this out? It seems that something similarly stopped working for me suddenly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/47098533#comment121863283_47098533

Comment: @Ryan Yeah it had something to do with my Chrome settings or some Chrome extension. I had to restore Chrome settings to their original defaults and it worked. I had set an answer also in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265727/googlesheets-google-script-run-always-going-to-failurehandler

Comment: @shanti Thanks. I figured out a solution, too, which I mentioned in my comment there.