# Post a Google Wallet shopping cart from UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-checkout

We have coded a highly specialized event registration system using Google Apps Script / UiApp, with data backed by a Google Docs spreadsheet and various other data sources.

The next step for us is to integrate with Google Wallet, so that we can process payments.  Users would start their sign-up in the UiApp based registration system, resulting in their detailed registration data being inserted into the spreadsheet, but with a status of pending-payment.  Then the user would click a Buy Now button or link to navigate to Google Wallet to complete their payment.

Is there a way to do this?  Has anyone successfully posted a shopping cart over to Google Wallet from a UiApp?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it myself but take a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Store_Gadget_How_To) with Google Sites gadget. In general if it works there, it will work with Apps Script.

You might need to transition to HtmlServices though.. perhaps only for the part that launches into the Wallet call (Checkout has been rebranded to Wallet).

Comment: What's the reason you say HtmlServices might be needed here?

Comment: Probably so the HTML can be more controlled/customized.  UiApp may not be able to pass the right arguments to Wallet

Answer (score 0):

You can add a link to UiApp as a workaround using anchor. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745403/3169358)

Basically the thing is:

```
 var link = app.createAnchor('A Link =D ',"http://your.link.com");
 app.add(link);
```

Hope it helps =)