# Open a Google Document in a browser window from a Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a template file in Google Docs. This template is to be copied and the newly created document presented to the user for editing in the browser.

I have a webapp where the user clicks a button and that runs the following code:

```
var theTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('[ID_of_the_template');
var theDocument=theTemplate.makeCopy("copy_for_me");
var num=theDocument.getId();
Logger.log(num);
```

This makes the copy and then in the variable "num" I have the document ID I need and all I now need is to open a link to
*https://docs.google.com/document/d/[docuID_here]/edit*
but I can find no way to do so.

I am sure this is easy but I can not find how to do it. Maybe I am thinking too complicated or am on the wrong track.
As always I appreciate any and all help.

Greetings from the Bavarian Alps.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url) if it can help you.

Comment: Than you @KENdi. This is the route that I took. It is not as "elegant" as I had hoped for but it works sucessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587781/is-there-a-way-to-open-a-new-document-from-a-google-docs-app-script). I do not believe this has changed in the past 3 years.  Basically, the portion of the script which creates the file is run on the server.

That said, IF your web app has a client side, you may be able to return the file link back to the client side and display it as a link for the user to open.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I had seen and read this answer but had hoped that as I am running my script as a webapp and this refers to a spreadsheet, there may be a method. I had also hoped that in the last few years there may have been an improvement in the situation.
Coming from a php background, I thought this would be something that was so obvious no one wrote about it. But now I will look for a different solution.
Thank you again.