# Nothing Happens when i use FormApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to load an existing google form from a spreadsheet using the simple example that create a custom menu and should load a form ready to add new responses

when  i save the function i am prompted to Allow permissions which i do . 
When i run the script - i dont get any messages but nothing happens. The form doesn't load . I thought the formapp command actually loaded the form

Is there a command to view the form or could you point me in direction of any scripts to view existing forms?

here is the script - am i missing something ?

```
`function launchForm() {

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
 ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
   .addItem('Open a form ', 'menuItem1')
  .addToUi();
 }

 function menuItem1() {

 var formID = '13hmg8VQgYHjrzgrPp33FQU6P3I4p5tFZvOs3p2T_xSc';
 var form = FormApp.openById(formID); 

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you open a Google form from a Custom Menu Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815296/how-do-you-open-a-google-form-from-a-custom-menu-item)

Answer (score 1):

The form is only 'programmatically' opened (so that the code has access to it). Do not expect a google script command to 'physically' open a form.

Comment: Is there a command to view the form or could you point me in direction of any scripts to view existing forms

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script can't open forms on the web browser, instead you have to manually click on the Google Form URL.