# how to open a document and show it user for editing?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to open a newly created google word document in another browser instance so that the user can interact with it.

I don't find any methods in the Document or the DocumentApp classes tailored for this requirement?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('My journal entry');
//now what if I want to open it for user editing?!!!
```

Comment: If you give more information about the context in which you create your document ( webapp, spreadsheet...? ) I could give a more developed example...

Comment: Key here is to create an anchor element (hyperlink) that uses the `getURL()` result. See this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47649/29140

Answer (score 1):

The [DocsList service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file?hl=fr-FR#getUrl%28%29) has a `getUrl()` method that you can use to get the url of your doc and use it in a UI to allow user to open it in a new Browser window.

You can find an example of such a Ui in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/10745403#10745403)

From the example you show you must at first get the ID of your document using [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document?hl=fr-FR#getId%28%29) and then use DocsList to retrieve the file.