# Google Apps Script: How can I call a form from a script embebed in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to build a script which can allow user to call a form from a function that I added to my spreadsheet menu using `addMenu("Menu_name", menuEntries)` method.

How can I implement this "go to live form" from inside my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a small UI with a link to the form (like any other URL). And add this function in your menu.

See this post for the code to create the UI: [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/10745403#10745403)

Comment: It's not possible directly open the form? (whithout having to click in the link)

Comment: I'm afraid not, GAS can't redirect a user without user action, even in this google-service to google-service configuration... that's part of their policy I guess