# Collating data from different google forms into one spreadsheet file?

Tags: google-forms

I wanted to know if there was a way to collate data from different forms in google forms.

My question is simple: Is there a way so that once a user completes and submits a set of forms, is there a way for the data to be automatically collated into one spreadsheet ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783279/updating-existing-data-on-google-spreadsheet-using-a-form

Comment: Need some more details on your current setup / code. You tagged Excel - are you using Google Sheets or trying to make an excel file?

Comment: just use the importRange spreadsheet function. a sample that consolidates many sheets using importRange is here https://zigmandel.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-i-crowd-translated-my-product-tour.html last section "consolidating status"