# How do I get Google Apps Script to open an external webpage and click on a button from that page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am wanting to move an application from excel VBA to Google Apps Script and I need to be able to open a webpage and click on a button from that webpage.  I have seen similar posts but clicking on the button was based on screen location.  I want to be able to click on a button regardless of screen location.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744760/1595451

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with apps-script to click a button on another page.
You need a client-side program for that.