# The simplest way to open a new window to show an HTML or URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

The simplest way to open a new window to show an HTML like this -

Arun Nagarajan said on this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13272748/edit

```
-<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Open in new window</a>-
```

I want to open a Link in my google document (no spreadsheet)
directely by menu or
by function !!

How to arrive with my script ?

```
  function onOpen() {
      // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
          DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('OAR')

          .addItem('MAJ  Date + OAR', 'test')
          .addItem('MAJ  Date  Auto', 'testdate')
         ***.addItem('Accès Direct URL', 'href=/d/1udvLSpaZNgalg6NId JMJvkkw3i9oCaEKa-A_CAC79CYkvsZKD545dyZN/edit?')***

           .addToUi();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open a new page , use the class Anchor in Google App Script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor?hl=fr

Comment: This method is deprecated in 2014 .https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor?hl=fr

Answer (score -1):

Looks like google scripts can't (don't allow us to) open links.
However you can show a dialog instructing the user..

since the UiApp is depreciated you can only use HtmlService to create HtmlOutput object then pass it to the UI

```
var content= 'You must go <a href="your_link">Here</a>';  //html as string
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content);  //the output is the HtmlOutput
DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'your_title');
```

or use `DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(..., ...)` if you don't want to prevent interaction with the document

and this will show the dialog with the wanted link

Check out this question
[Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url)

Answer (score -4):

I think this will help you, with only JS.
In parameter you can put the url you want as a string.

```
window.open(url);
```

Comment: I put this but don't work .function onOpen() {
      // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
          DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('OAR').addItem('Appel Ro Paramedical', 'openropara')
      
    .addToUi();
}


function oninstall() {
   onOpen()
   }

function openropara() {
window.open('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1omBMnoX4_Yf_5ooUxIFlZGYbx5PdlGqpwHIaezBnZnw/edit');
}

Comment: Because the answer is incorrect. Does not apply to apps script

Comment: My question is well posted in Google App Script.Perhaps not well formuled ..... how to do for this please ?