# How to Redirect the One URL to Another URL in google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Script user receiving email with Image, Once user click the image i want automatically go to another URL like(www.google.com)
I used the below coding in google Script

```
function sendEmails()
{

var message    = GmailApp.getDraftMessages()[0];
var bodyText   = message.getBody();
var rawContent = message.getRawContent();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var  numRows = (sheet.getLastRow())-1; 
Logger.log(numRows);
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
Logger.log(data)
for (i in data)
{
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress =row[0];
var Name=row[1];
var googleLogoUrl = row[3];
var url = sheet.getRange("c"+i).getValue();
var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                  .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                   .getBlob()
                   .setName("Test");
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to:test@example.com,
     subject: "test",
     htmlBody: "<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>",
     inlineImages:
       {
        googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,   
       }
       });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks brian, i get the answer

Comment: Related comment by brian that was deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/