# openByUrl() does nothing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Brand new at this.

I thought the following code in Google Apps Script would simply open a sheet in another window. But nothing happened. Nothing.

Here's my code:

```
function OpenaSheet() {
  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs---------Blanked out on purpose-------------')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)) was meant to access your google spreadsheet as shown in the docs.

Another way to access your gsheet is by `openById`. So `openByUrl` doesn't literally mean it will open a provided Url but instead a means to access the spreadsheet. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745403) for that purpose.