# Adding filter views to custom menu in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just want to confirm that we currently **cannot** add saved filter views to custom menus.

Currently to access pre-saved Filter Views users have to go Data \ Filter Views \ etc.

I'd like to add a custom menu at the top level for them called "Our Views" and just list the custom views directly under that.

Making the custom menus seem easy, but my understanding is that there is still no way to get a hook on a saved filter view and open it. Nothing like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('FilterView1', 'OpenFilterView1')
      .addToUi();
}

function OpenFilterView1(){
    openSavedFilter("Our First Filter View")
}
```

Comment: Filter views have their URLs, so the task is to open a link. You may like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098533/5372400

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you!