# How to open a website from a cell in google sheets by clicking a button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making an spreadsheet in google sheets where I've got several links to pre-filled google forms https://docs.google.com/forms
. I added a 'button' in the spreadsheet which, when you click it, navigates to the cell containing the right link to the pre-filled form (16 cells to the right of the current active cell), which looks like;

```
function GoToSite(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Returns the active cell
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
cell.offset(0,16).activate();
};
```

However, I don't manage to get the spreadsheet to open this link. I know that in a normal excel file, you would use something looking like;

```
Sub openwebpage ()
... 
End Sub
```

And you would use "FollowHyperlink"/ "create an IE object" / ".Navigate" or maybe even "Sendkeys" (if you enter alt+enter when the cell containing the pre-filled link is selected, this opens the webpage). But all these options are in combination with sub .. end sub and I don't manage the macro to recognise this. It seems to only work with

```
function example (){
...
};
```

Maybe I'm doing something totally wrong. Is there someone who would know how to open the link in the cell by using macros? Or how to use "Sub ...  End Sub" in an google sheet?

Thanks

Comment: VBA (Sub / End Sub) and JavaScript are fundamentally different. The closest you can come is to use the server functions to fetch the webpage, and then display the response HTML in a modal dialog. This is also because Google Apps Script runs on a remote server, not your browser (Excel VBA is running on your local machine, with access to your operating system, browser, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! I am not yet familiar with all the differences between VBA/JavaScript etc. I'm trying to figure it out and keep learning every day. This should help me further

Comment: @DieuwertjeDrexhage How did you get on with your Google Sheets problem with opening hyperlinks?

Comment: @Tedinoz I've got to admit I have not really figure it out yet, when I have I'll let you know!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the below code in your Script Editor and pass through a `url` as its parameter.

```
/**
 * Open a URL in a new tab.
 */
function openUrl( url ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

The solution's author points out that you will not be able to run this code in the Script Editor directly and you'll need to Assign the script to a drawing or button.

[Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/47098533#47098533)