# How do I use GAE to listen to Google sheets and then run a set of python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Hey all I am looking to use GAE to listen to one of my Google sheets pages and then  execute a python script based of what was entered. I have already setup the python and sheets interaction, meaning I can now read everything off my sheet when I run my code. I am having trouble understanding how to setup GAE to "listen" for changes an the sheets though. I have setup the GAE using:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

But not sure how to integrate this using my sheets. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is doable but not in the same way you described. GAE cannot listen to Google Sheets. The usually interaction is with the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/), which will require you firing off API calls to check for a certain sheet/cell for updates.

Since you are looking for a "push" solution, you will need to do it from Google Sheets' end. You need Google Sheets to fire off a request to your GAE and then you can process the information. I would suggest you code your GAE handler to process GET requests and then have your Google Sheets fire off [a script to set a request to your GAE URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744760/4092401). You will set the script to trigger whenever the desired update on your sheet is performed.