# Is there a way to script clickable button links without showing a dialog pop up?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm attaching a script to a button, that upon click, it opens a brand new tab to the desired link within my script. However, I can't seem to get rid of the dialog box which makes me interact with my link and becomes redundant. How would one achieve this?

I have looked into `e.preventDefault()` and `(window).blur(function()` to see if these would lead me to the right direction, but still evokes a dialog box.

```
function openForm(){

  var html = "<script> window.open('Any Link In Here');</script>";

}
```

How I expect this to work is by clicking on my button, it'll just open a brand new tab to any desired link I want, however nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Credit to @Tedinoz for helping me and for finding this link [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url).

In this link 'TheMaster' provided an excellent answer. Two things are working here, an HTML source and a javascript. Within the HTML is `var winRef = window.open(url1);` which opens the URL in another tab, however a dialog box opens.
The next line shows

`winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Allow popup to redirect you to '+url1) ;`

What this seems to do is closes the dialog box within google sheet, which appears to be this section

`winRef ? google.script.host.close()`

So in short, when setting this up name the HTML file whatever you want, with the Javascript, make sure line 6 on the javascript reflects the same name as the HTML source.

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(50), // 'openUrl is the name of the HTML source, name this whatever.
```

Once done, go to your button, attach the script which you name it by the javascript function `modalUrl`.

Here is the full script. If 'TheMaster' ever sees this, please let me know if I nailed  what I said above.

**openUrl.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <base target="_blank">
    <script>
     var url1 ='https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675103';
     var winRef = window.open(url1);
     winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Allow popup to redirect you to '+url1) ;
     window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('url').href = url1;}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Kindly allow pop ups</br>
    Or <a id='url'>Click here </a>to continue!!!
  </body>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function modalUrl(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .showModalDialog(
     HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(50),
     'Opening StackOverflow'
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```js
function openForm(){
  var html = "<script> window.open('Any Link In Here', '_blank');</script>";
}
```

Comment: When using the Function you provided, I get an error showing "_RefereneError: Window is not defined_" after I have clicked my button. Any idea what this might be?

Comment: Mmh, I didn't see the google-sheets tag. You made this script in google doc?

Comment: Something odd, so using the updated script seems fine, however, once I attach it to the button, I get the notifications at the top saying Script Finished, however, it will not open any link. Here is a copy of my sheet. Please ask for permission as this is under a work account.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFlBlVuGgHRD96fqIAGdlQLohCmwjmxILt95KZNJ_2A/edit?usp=sharing