# Open a URL on Form Submit Event - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using the sample code provided by Serge insas found here:
[Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url)

I have modified the code slightly as seen below:

**Code.GS**

```
   function modalUrl(){
      FormApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(
         HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(50),
         'Opening StackOverflow'
       )
    }
```

**openURL.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <base target="_blank">
    <script>
     var url1 ='https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675103';
     var winRef = window.open(url1);
     winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.alert('Allow popup to redirect you to '+url1) ;
     window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('url').href = url1;}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Kindly allow pop ups</br>
    Or <a id='url'>Click here </a>to continue!!!
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue is appears is that it is not possible to access FormApp.getUi after a form has been submitted.
See the error below:
[image]

Comment: Like the error says, You cannot do that. User needs to click a menu in the editor to open the popup.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate, but thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation regarding [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) class:

> A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an
>   open editor, and only if the script is container-bound to the editor.

In the case of a Google Form, the editor is when you're editing a specific form and not when you're filling one. You can't automatically redirect a user after a form submission if the form is not embedded in a website, may be the workaround in this support [article](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/7014160) can help you.