# Google Sheet - Turn on Offline mode unpon opening

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, offline-mode, multiple-users

My objective here is to let multiple users change the file at the same time without disrupting others. I think that the offline mode is the answer. That's why I'm searching for a way to turn on the offline mode editing when a user opens it.

Maybe offline mode is not the most efficient way, I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Kindly check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead is copy the sheet and let them work on the duplicated sheet. Use the code below.

#### Code:

```
function openDuplicatedSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetName = spreadsheet.getName();

  // Duplicated file id
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.create("Copy of " + spreadsheetName).getId();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  // Rename sheet so it won't be duplicated
  destination.renameActiveSheet("temp-sheet-to-be-removed-later)");
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  // Copy the sheets excluding the script so it won't duplicate infinitely
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet, index) {
    sheet.copyTo(destination);
    // Use sheet name from the original sheet
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    destination.getSheets()[index + 1].activate();
    destination.renameActiveSheet(sheetName);
  });
  // Remove default Sheet1 which was renamed earlier to avoid duplication of sheet name
  destination.deleteSheet(destination.getSheets()[0]);

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileId + '/" target="_blank">' + spreadsheetName + '</a>')
    .setWidth(350) 
    .setHeight(50); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Click to open duplicated sheet');
}
```

#### Trigger:

[image: trigger]

#### Prompt upon opening:

[image: prompt]

#### Output:

[image: duplicate]

This will create a duplicate/copy of the content of the file (excluding the script) and should be accessible to their own drives.

#### Note:

- There is a little delay with the pop window. Just wait for it to show up.
- Use the duplicated file to avoid multiple duplicates of the original file.
- The duplicated file won't further duplicate as its script was not included in the copy.

#### Reference:

- [duplicate spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884941/duplicate-a-model-spreadsheet-and-open-the-copy-by-google-script)