# GoogleSheets google.script.run always going to FailureHandler

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using GoogleSheets HTMLService. I am calling google.script.run from my Html page's script. But it is always going to FailureHandler. What is wrong in it? Please see the code below. When I run it, it always shows the alert Failed. Also, the logger does not show any error. It is also not showing the console log "Inside Hello" in the hello() function. Do we also need to do some browser settings (I am using chrome - javascript allowed).

[UPDATED]
After replacing Logger.log with console.log, I am seeing it as Transport Error.

[image]

```
modeDialog.gs

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("test");
  html.setWidth(90).setHeight(1);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Opening ..." );
}

function hello() {
  console.log("Inside Hello");
  return "hello";
}


test.html

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
  function onSuccess(str) {
  window.alert("executed");
  }
  
  function onFailure(error) {
  window.alert("failed");
  Logger.log(error);
  }
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).hello();
  
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="failureContent"></div>
    Hello world
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: `Logger` is not available  client side. Use `console` instead. Look in Dev Tools> Browser console for error logs

Comment: In your case, I thought that an error like `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500` might occur for `google.script.run`. In my environment,also I had confirmed such situation using `google.script.run`. In that case, when I create new Spreadsheet and copy and paste the script to the script editor and run again, the issue was removed. So in your environment, when you will do this, what result will you obtain? In the current stage, I cannot find this issue at the issue tracker. So I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: try putting it into a `window.onload`

Comment: @TheMaster I tried with console.log, there was TransportError. I will update my question with error.

Comment: @Tanaike After looking into DevTools > console, I am getting TransportError. I will update my question with this error

Comment: @Cooper I tried it with window.onLoad, it is still giving transport error

Comment: @Tanaike I created a new spreadsheet, copied all the scripts and ran it, still getting TransportError and Failed to load Resource error

Comment: BTW html setHeight() is in pixels  so 1 is a little small.  I don't know of any font that's only one pixel high. I chose the default settings in my answer.

Comment: @shanti I am not sure whether Transport error matters. What makes you think `hello` didn't run? Have you checked server logs? View> executions?

Comment: @TheMaster yeah I had put a console.log() statement there as well. And server log accepts console.log() as well (I have earlier used it). It did not show up. Tried with Logger.log() as well. I am looking in View > Executions

And the worst part is, this code was working a few days back. Now when I am trying it, it's just not working..That's why I am thinking, did I change anything in my chrome settings that affected it...

Comment: Alright, so I tried on FireFox and it is going to the success handler and showing the alert "Executed". Something wrong with chrome...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'm getting `executed`, even when using Chrome.

Comment: @Iamblichus It was working for me in Chrome initially. But when I tried it again after a couple of days, it stopped working in Chrome. It is still working in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned that it was working earlier in Chrome and is currently working in FireFox, I tested it again after changing my chrome settings to default by going to Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up > Restore settings to their original defaults.

It is working fine after that. So setting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it this way:

GS:

```
function openDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah3"), "Opening ..." );
}

function hello() {
  return "hello";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world
    <script>
    window.onload=function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(str){window.alert("executed");})
      .withFailureHandler(function(error){window.alert("failed");})
      .hello();
    }  
    console.log('MyCode');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just like to use onReadyState function or onload to run most javascript so that html is already loaded.  Not that it makes much difference in this trivial example.  Also I tend to put the scripts in the body rather than in the head.

Comment: I copied your answer and ran it, it is still giving failed :( and in dev console again Transport Error & 2451951077-waffle_js_prod_core.js:471 GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: I get transport errors like that all of the time.  Honestly, I don't know what the problem is and in the end I don't care as long as my scripts run and they do do so I have quit worrying about them.

Comment: ok, but it's not even executing my hello() function...

Comment: Obviously I can't confirm that

Comment: did you change 'ah3' back to 'test'. 'ah3' is the name of my html file

Comment: yeah, I put the name of my html file

Comment: I can confirm that hello() is not getting executed because my Logger.log()/console.log() inside hello() isn't showing up in server logs (View > Excecutions) (Normally, both work in server logs)

Comment: I think it has to do something with some browser setting (in chrome). I am not sure what. But when I tried in Firefox, it is working fine. Even my earlier code (without window.onload) is working fine...

Comment: Popups are allowed...I don't know what setting is causing this...