# Google Script to make a hyperlink (for a button)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know much about script, but I am trying to make a clickable button on Google Sheets that would hyperlink to another website. For some reason google sheets doesn't let you hyperlink a google drawing. :/

I know how to assign script to a button (aka a google drawing inserted into my google sheet), but I don't know the actual script that would hyperlink the button to another website.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `=HYPERLINK()`?

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create button by going to Insert -> Drawing.
2. Draw the button then click Save and Close.
3. Once you created your button, Go to Tools -> Script Editor
4. Paste the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098533) by Stephen M. Harris:

Your code should look like this:

```
//change the value of url to your desired url.
function openUrl( url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url" ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

5. Click Save or Ctrl + S.
6. Run the code and authorize the script to access your data.
7. Go back to your Spreadsheet where the button is located.
8. Right click the button and click the vertical 3 dots
9. Click Assign Script and type the function name "openUrl" ("This is the function from your Apps Script")
10. Press then button

**Note:** This might not work on your first run due to PopUp Blocker, [allow the site](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472) and re-click the button.