# Cannot call getUI from this context when using google.script.run

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I'm making a program that will automatically open the launch meeting page to take me to my next ZOOM class on time, and our schools have 'a days' and 'b days', each with a different schedule, so I have an HTML page that has two buttons, one that will trigger the schedule for an A day and another that triggers the schedule for a B day. I'm testing the functions that will open the new tab and run that function from the HTML, but when I run it from the HTML, I get an error message in my executions that says cannot call DocumentApp.getUI from this context. My code is here, if you put it into GAS you can see for yourself.

Part of my code came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098533/14543232)

My code.gs file

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html');
}
function openUrl( url ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
function LaZoom(){
openUrl('https://op97-org.zoom.us/j/9622570589');
}
```

My HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<button onclick = 'aDay()'>A day</button>
<button onclick = 'bDay()'>B day</button>
</html>
<script>
function aDay(){
 google.script.run.LaZoom();
 alert('ran')
}


</script>
```

Comment: If you get/post code from stackoverflow, you should  provide attribution under cc licence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this client side using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) instead of going back and forth between server and client.

```
function aDay(){window.open('A_URL')}
```