# Download file from drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've an app script that create a PDF file, and return the download url to the client, but the file is not downloadable if the user does not have access.

I got [this](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MQ1ktUEEHGFjr5sgc_UqB7TSTcOW1gRP&export=download) url generated by the code below, how can I make it downloadable regardless for any one click it.

```
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName(REPORT);  
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  var link = newFile.getDownloadUrl()
  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  return link;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744760/1595451)

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide your whole script for replicating your current issue? And, can I ask you about the method for executing your script?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to grant everyone permissions in the selected sheet? You want to set the permissions to "available to everyone" with Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an ui and open a new tab with your url from there. Like this

[image]

In main approach you need call

```js
const newWin = window.open(url, "_blank");
```

after you created the file.

See this snippet for full explanation https://google-apps-script-snippets.contributor.pw/snippets/common_ui/open_url_in_browser/

Comment: What is In calling it from web app

Comment: Any user action. It may be menu click or user trigger. But it should always be a user scope.