# Creating a view history log every time someone accesses a google doc and/or copies it using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I wrote a script to log who and when opens a google doc. It works fine but the doc is a template for users to fill in so want to ensure whoever needs it will make a copy of the template through apps script.

I know users need edit access for the script to work but in terms of workarounds:

1. Is there a way for the script to still work if I give them a copy link or a template link?
   Does it make more sense to use the google sheet as the base and pull from the google doc ID?

If that doesn't work than:
2) Is there a way to prompt them with a menu window to copy the file but delay it by x seconds on open?

```
//setups a count for the file
function setup() {
  var propertyService = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  propertyService.setProperty('viewCount', '0');
}

//logs the email and date of the user accessing the file
function onOpen(e) {
 var count = parseInt(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('viewCount'))+1;
 PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('viewCount', count);
 Logger.log(count);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById([spreadsheet ID]);
 var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var date = new Date();

 sheet.getSheetByName('View Count').appendRow([user,date]);
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. I understand that you want to expand your script to include logs about who and when copy that Doc, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

You can add a menu item that creates a copy of the template for the user, logs the copy to the same sheet where you track who opens the file, and prompts the user to open their copy of the file to start working.

### Steps

First: add these 3 functions.

1. The first, `copyFile`, creates a copy of the active document and names it the same plus the user's email. Then it logs the activity to the same change log, adding the new file's ID to the row. Finally, thanks to [this nifty function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url) it pops up a window with a link to the new file so the user can easily open it and start working.
2. The second, `showAnchor`, is the function that generates the HTML dialog box which presents the user a link to their new file.
3. The third, `createMenu`, adds a new menu item to the Google Docs nav bar, which prompts the user to copy the document. This, of course, triggers the `copyFile` function.

```
function copyFile() {
  var thisDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById([spreadsheet ID]);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  var date = new Date();
  
  var newCopy =  DriveApp.getFileById(thisDoc.getId()).makeCopy(thisDoc.getName() + " " + user)

  sheet.getSheetByName('View Count').appendRow([user,date,newCopy.getId()]);

  var url = newCopy.getUrl()
  showAnchor('Open Your File',url);
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui," ");
}



function createMenu() {
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu("Copy This Template");
  menu.addItem("Copy", "copyFile");
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Then: add a call to `createMenu()` at the end of your onOpen script:

```
function onOpen(e) {
 var count = parseInt(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('viewCount'))+1;
 PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('viewCount', count);
 Logger.log(count);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById([spreadsheet ID]);
 var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var date = new Date();

 sheet.getSheetByName('View Count').appendRow([user,date]);

 createMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to keep a record of each user who accessed a given google doc.  This worked well for my needs:

I began by using the Script Properties.
Within Apps Script click on the cog icon (left hand nav) and at the bottom of the screen are Script Properties.  I created a property of "viewers" with a value of "{}" (no quotes around any of that).

```
const PROP_SERVICE = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

const onOpen = () => {
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    date = new Date().toLocaleString(),
    viewers = JSON.parse(PROP_SERVICE.getProperty('viewers')),
    user = email.split('@')[0];
  addView({viewers, user, email, date});
};

const addView = ({viewers, user, email, date}) => {
  if (viewers[user]) {
    viewers[user].count++;
  } else {
    viewers[user] = { 
      count : 1, 
      visits : [],
      email
    };
  }
  viewers[user].visits.push(date);
  console.log(`Added view for ${user}`);
  saveView(viewers);
};

const saveView = viewers => {
  PROP_SERVICE.setProperty('viewers', JSON.stringify(viewers));
  console.log('view saved');
};

const logEverything = () => {
  const viewers = JSON.parse(PROP_SERVICE.getProperty('viewers'));

  for (user in viewers) {
    console.log(`User ${user} has visited ${viewers[user].count} time/s with email ${viewers[user].email}.`);
    console.log(viewers[user].visits);
  }
};
```

This will create a log of each account that accesses the document.  The data is stored as JSON within the Script Properties and it will persist.

Each time the document is opened it will log who viewed the document and confirm that the save took place.

There is also a function named logEverything you can run manually that will just iterate through all of the data and log everything at once.

For each user this will track:

- how many times the user accessed the document
- the dates of each visit (this can readily be adjusted if you need time details)
- the full email of the user

This could be adjusted to just see people who've logged in within a given period of time (the last week/month/year), or to break up time into increments and log viewers from each week/month/year.  This wasn't designed to handle anonymous users.