# How to start a Google Slides presentation after creating it using a script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

The user accesses a Spreadsheet and requests the application create a Proposal (which is a Google Slides app). The Spreadsheet performs this action using Google scripts. The user would like to immediately open and review the Proposal without closing out of the original Spreadsheet. I know I can ask the question of whether they would like to open the Proposal using a ui.alert. I kow how to open the new Proposal but I don't know how to give it focus on the screen or tranfser control to it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a presentation, you have to make your script to open the presentaion in presentation mode. To do this first you have to build the URL:

```
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${presentation.getId()}/present`;
```

Then you might open a dialog or sidebar including client side code to open the URL as is done with any URL. For this you might use the function openURL from the [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098533/1595451) to  [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744760/1595451):

```
/**
 * Open a URL in a new tab.
 */
function openUrl( url ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer for a Windows based solution. I have two more requirements that need to be fulfilled:
1. Needs to work on Windows and MACs
2. Need to open the new presentation for update not just view only.
Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: I have figured out to allow EDIT instead of view only, just change the value in 'const url' to have 'edit' instead of 'present' as per:
const url = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${presentation.getId()}/edit`;

Now just have to figure out how to make this work on MACs and Windows PC!!!

Comment: @IraKirschner I'm glad that you figured out one part of your query. Regarding the other part, I suggest you to post a new question including details of othe target web-browsers (name and version).