# Can the same Google Apps Script script that opened the tab, also close the tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

This question: [Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744760/google-apps-script-to-open-a-url/47098533#comment121863283_47098533) leaves one thing unanswered: After opening the URL, can the script close the tab (or window) used to open the URL? Specifically, I'm using the code from that post to open a PDF for printing. After printing, and closing the PDF file, the tab opened by the script remains. Can the same script that opened the tab ("_blank"), also close the tab?

```
<script> window.open('<?=url?>', '_blank', 'width=100, height=100'); 
google.script.host.close(); 
window.close(); 
</script>
```

The code above comes from code posted by [stephen-m-harris](https://%5B2%5Dhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/445295/stephen-m-harris)

Comment: Yes⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Ah. That is good to know. Thank you. Now that we know it's possible would you, TheMASTER, happen to have the working code to do so; and, if so having, would you be willing to share that code here, in this thread; and if willing, would you actually show, for the world to see -- but specifically, me --  the line-by-line apps script ES6 code that accomplishes the objective requested above?

Comment: Alternate proposal: You read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close and show what you've tried with debugging details, if you're unable to accomplish the task.

Comment: I've tried window.close(). Nothing happens, that is, the tab opened by the script code to open the URL does not close.

Comment: Comments are not for adding code. [Edit] your question to post your code, a [mre] and I'll add a answer.

Comment: If you're adding someone else's code, make sure to given them appropriate credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window` refers to the current window. To close the window that was opened, you should call [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) on that widow. [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) gives a reference to the window that was opened.

```
<script> 
  const openedWindow = window.open('<?=url?>', '_blank', 'width=100, height=100'); 
  //google.script.host.close(); 
  setTimeout(() => openedWindow.close(), 5000);
  const closeSelf = () => openedWindow.closed && google.script.host.close();
  setInterval(closeSelf, 5000) 
</script>
```

A timeout is added because the  `openedWindow` might not have been loaded and may not respond to `.close()` request as soon as it was opened. `setInterval` is used to check if the window is closed every 5s and if closed, close the current window too.

Comment: The most recent update with setTimeout, etc. code works! Thanks so much for providing the solution. I think I understand how it works, but I don't understand the purpose of the arrow function technique here. This seems like a unique use of that syntax. Can you explain?

Comment: @Kevin No unique use. Just normal arrow syntax. In `setTimeout` however, it gives access to  enclosing context's `this`( though it isn't important in this case). See `this` problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout `The most recent update` Do you mean the original one didn't work?

Comment: @Kevin I added the reason for `setTimeout` in the answer. I didn't test any of it, for your question. All of it was just based on previous experience.

Comment: Correct. I didn't save a screen shot, but every attempt to print the file produced a Google message page that I interpreted to mean the file no longer existed.

Comment: Regarding the use of arrow syntax, why wouldn't this work for closing the window:
setTimeout(openedWindow.close(), 5000); ?

Comment: Ok. I read the referenced "this" problem on the `setTimeout` page. A bit steep, but I'll let it sink in and read it again. It also answered my last question, so thanks for the reference.