# Use button to open URL in new window with Google Appsscript

Tags: url, hyperlink, google-apps-script

I am writing an application for the new Google Sheets to integrate another API with Sheets. I need to authorize the user by opening a new window allowing the user to login to authorize my app.

So far the only way I have found to do this is with a simple hyperlink. Is there a way to do this with a button that calls a function on the backend? I can't figure out anything that works to open a link in a new window when a user clicks on a button.

NOTE: I want to do this to be consistent with the UI. I need to add an "authorize" and a "deauthorize" button. The deauthorize button just calls a function to delete the access token from the users account, but the authorize button needs to open a new URL to send the user to another site to login.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind when you talk about buttons in the context of a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using an auto open sidebar, it looks like this :

[image]

and the code below :

```
function onOpen() {
  var shUi = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Custom functions');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createHTML('please select an option below').setStyleAttribute('padding','10px'));
  var grid = app.createGrid(1,2).setWidth('200');
  var dHandler = app.createServerHandler('removeAuth');
  var b1 = app.createButton("Authorize");
  var b2 = app.createButton("De-authorize",dHandler).setTitle('remove authorization');
  var link = app.createAnchor('XXXXX','http://www.google.com').setStyleAttributes({'zIndex':'1' , 'position':'fixed' , 'top':'45' , 'left':'20', 'color':'transparent' }).setTitle('proceed in a new tab');
  var G1 = app.createVerticalPanel().add(b1).add(link);
  grid.setWidget(0,0,G1).setWidget(0,1,b2);
  app.add(panel).add(grid)
  shUi.showSidebar(app);
}

function removeAuth(){
  // some code
}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! I was going to build my UI with the HTML service and overlooked the new UI builder. It is interesting it doesn't look like there is any way to do this with the HTML service.

Comment: actually it is doable with html service but I'm more comfortable with uiApp so I choose the easy way ;-)

Comment: A rewrite in `HtmlService` wouldn't be a bad idea now that `UiApp` is deprecated. Then we don't have to feel guilty about flagging "GAS Open URL" questions as duplicates of this one :)

Answer (score 0):

In Apps-script you can't open a new tab with button click events, But this can be made through 
Anchors. So create a anchor and set the Href with the link to be opened in a new tab. To get a Button feel you can set the StyleAttribute for the anchor with a background-image property.

```
var anchor1 = app.createAnchor('Authorize','http://www.google.com')
                 .setStyleAttribute('backgroundImage','url('tree.png')');
```